# Autosizing UITableViewCell programatically based on content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an application what simulates chatting with a real user, for chat log layout i am using `UITableView`, because i am very new to Swift, but used to program with other languages, i am creating whole layout programatically.

Currently my `ViewController` looks like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let rows: [String] = [
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam euismod nunc id nulla ultricies tempus. Mauris a euismod nunc."
    ]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rows.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AiMessageCell") as! AiMessageCell

//        cell.textLabel?.text = rows[indexPath.row]
//        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//        tableView.beginUpdates()
//        tableView.endUpdates()

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
//        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

        tableView.register(AiMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AiMessageCell")
        tableView.register(UserMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UserMessageCell")
        tableView.register(UserSelectionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UserSelectionCell")
    }
}
```

it just takes single row and based on it (currently not passing text to cell) outputs one single row to my `UITableView`

and i have `AiMessageCell` logic

```
class AiMessageCell: UITableViewCell, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {

//    @IBOutlet weak var wrapper: UIView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let wrapper = UIView(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: 10, y: 10,
                width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10 - 10,
                height: 45
            )
        )

        let balloon = UIView(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: 40, y: 0,
                width: 80,
                height: 45.5
            )
        )
        balloon.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        balloon.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(
            red: CGFloat(240/255.0),
            green: CGFloat(240/255.0),
            blue: CGFloat(240/255.0),
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        );

        let message = UITextView(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: 10, y: 5,
                width: balloon.layer.bounds.width - 10,
                height: balloon.layer.bounds.height - 10
            )
        );
        message.text = "What is shown in the scrollable content area of a scroll view is determined by its subviews. ";
        message.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16);
        message.isEditable = false;
        message.isScrollEnabled = false;
        message.isSelectable = false;
        message.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        message.layoutManager.delegate = self;

        let avatar = UIImageView(
            image: UIImage(named: "avatar")
        );

        avatar.clipsToBounds = true;
        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = 15;

        let calculated = message.sizeThatFits(
            CGSize(width: wrapper.bounds.width - 50, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        )

        avatar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: calculated.height - 25, width: 30, height: 30)

        message.frame.size = CGSize(width: calculated.width, height: calculated.height)
        balloon.frame.size = CGSize(width: calculated.width + 20, height: calculated.height + 5);
        wrapper.frame.size = CGSize(width: wrapper.bounds.width, height: balloon.bounds.height);

        balloon.addSubview(message)

        wrapper.addSubview(balloon)
        wrapper.addSubview(avatar)

        wrapper.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        contentView.addSubview(wrapper)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setTimeout(_ delay:TimeInterval, block:@escaping ()->Void) -> Void {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delay, target: BlockOperation(block: block), selector: #selector(Operation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager, lineSpacingAfterGlyphAt glyphIndex: Int, withProposedLineFragmentRect rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

here i am constructing whole message row, with "user" avatar, and message bubble (`UITextView`), which autosizes to text.

**And here comes the problem, despite message bubble is autosizing to text, table row height is fixed.**

This is how it looks like, i honestly tried at least 5 different answers from SO, but no luck.  Currently i think that problem is because i don't have constraints between my `wrapper` (purple block) and cells `content view` (green block)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check constraint in your storyboard. It's seems like you're forget constraint from bottom text block to bottom cell. And then uncomment this

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that you are defining the cell subviews sizes with frame and not with layout constraints. When you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` you need to properly setup the constraints to the top and the bottom of the UITableViewCell.

And instead of using the delegate, I think it's much cleaner the way you have commented in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```